# How to make the conversion NaN >> [''] to all the elements of a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 6, 4], np.nan, [1, 2]],
    'B': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 7, 9], np.nan, [4, 5]],
    'E': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'F': [[2, 2], [4, 4], np.nan, [78, 90], np.nan]
})

# First try
# ERROR: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
# df[df.isnull()] = df[df.isnull()].applymap(lambda x: [''])

# Second try
# ERROR: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'float'
# df.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=[''], inplace=True)

# Third try
# RESULT: The column 'E' dissapears and the rest of NaN values are converted to None
# stack = df.stack()
# stack[stack.isnull()] = ['']    # or stack[stack == np.nan] = ['']    
# stack.unstack()

# Fourth try
# ERROR: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"
# df.fillna([''])
```

This is my expected result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 6, 4], [''], [1, 2]],
    'B': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 7, 9], [''], [4, 5]],
    'E': [[''], [''], [''], [''], ['']],
    'F': [[2, 2], [4, 4], [''], [78, 90], ['']]
})
```

I have tried all the ways shown in the example with no results. How to achieve this?

**Note**: I want to point out that the replacement is a list with only one element, an empty string. Also, it could be `[np.nan]`

Comment: Side note: Are you sure you want an empty string in `F`, which appears to be a numeric column? Adding a string will turn the entire series to `object` dtype, which is expensive and inefficient.

Comment: @jpp actually all are lists, and I want to replace the NaN values with a list of one element, a empty string. I have updated my question. Take a look at it, thanks

Comment: This makes my point *even more* important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [136]: df.applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])
Out[136]:
                 A                B   E         F
0     [1, 2, 3, 4]     [1, 2, 3, 4]  []    [2, 2]
1  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  []    [4, 4]
2        [7, 6, 4]        [3, 7, 9]  []        []
3               []               []  []  [78, 90]
4           [1, 2]           [4, 5]  []        []
```

or:

```
In [152]: df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [np.nan])

In [153]: df
Out[153]:
                 A                B      E         F
0     [1, 2, 3, 4]     [1, 2, 3, 4]  [nan]    [2, 2]
1  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  [nan]    [4, 4]
2        [7, 6, 4]        [3, 7, 9]  [nan]     [nan]
3            [nan]            [nan]  [nan]  [78, 90]
4           [1, 2]           [4, 5]  [nan]     [nan]
```

**NOTE:** please pay attention at [@jpp's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966435/how-to-make-the-conversion-nan-to-all-the-elements-of-a-pandas-dataframe#comment88929330_50966435) - storing non-scalar values in cells destroys 90% of Pandas/Numpy magic, as most of fast internal vectorized methods expect scalar values in cells - they will not work or won't work as expected.

---

**Answer for the data set *before* the question has been updated:**

you can do it:

```
In [120]: df = df.fillna('')

In [121]: df
Out[121]:
       A      B         C         D E   F
0   zero    one  0.226100  1.764036     2
1    one    one -1.672476 -0.867188     2
2    two         0.671258  0.125589     4
3  three  three  1.135731  0.080577     4
4   four    two -1.711692  0.735028    67
5           two  0.608488  1.012977
6    six    one -1.233979 -0.623781    78
7  seven  three  0.256893 -0.546639    90
```

but all columns containing at least one `NaN` value will be converted to strings, because an empty string `''` will always have a string (`object`) `dtype`:

```
In [122]: df.dtypes
Out[122]:
A     object
B     object
C    float64
D    float64
E     object
F     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Mmm actually what I want to replace is a list with one element, and this element is a empty string: `['']`

Comment: @ChesuCR, can you post your desired data set in your question?

Comment: OK I will try to be more clear. I will update my question in a moment

Comment: I have updated my question, take a look at it please, thanks

Comment: @ChesuCR, i've updated my answer. Basically it'll convert any non-list cell into an empty list. Please let me know if you might have scalar values in cells and what to do with them in this case?

Comment: @ShashankSingh, yes

Comment: OK, so taking into account the @jpp comment I can replace the value with `[np.nan]` instead of `['']` because if I use an empty list `[]` the result is not valid for me (for the plotting library that I am using). Will be that OK? So your answer is working well for that replacement as well.

Comment: @ChesuCR, sure you can use `[np.nan]` instead of `[]`, but jpp's main point was about storing non-scalar values in cells... ;-)

Comment: Aah!! You mean the lists? I need to store lists, I do not have any other option